# `BaseSettings` has been moved to the `pydantic-settings` for pandas profiling

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to run pandas profiling. I'm running Python version 3.8.10 .

I wrote following command to install pandas profiling
`pip install pydantic-settings`
After that while I'm trying to import profile report using below command
`from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport`

I'm getting error message

```
PydanticImportError: `BaseSettings` has been moved to the `pydantic-settings` package. See https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.6/migration/#basesettings-has-moved-to-pydantic-settings for more details.
```

In this page it's saying that `BaseSettings, the base object for Pydantic settings management, has been moved to a separate package, pydantic-settings.` After that I installed pydantic-settings  using following command `pip install pydantic-settings`  But I'm still getting the same error.

Tried following things:

```
pip install ydata-profiling

import pandas as pd
from ydata_profiling import ProfileReport

# Read the data from a csv file


# Generate the data profiling report
report = ProfileReport(pandas_jd, title='Profile Report of my data')
report.to_file("my_report.html")
```

and I'm getting error message

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.stats._mvn'
```

Can you please guide me to resolve the issue?

Comment: What's the full error message?

Comment: @ForceBru, I'm getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.stats._mvn'. I can't able to paste the full error message as it is too long by 6879 characters